# Plot datetime.timedelta

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime, timedelta

I am working on a task, where I need to calculate time spent on each day and then represent that time using a bar plot, so for this task I used python and able to get time spent on each day, and stored it in a list "time_list", now I don't understand how to plot this using matplotlib function.

The problem is that, this list contains datetime.timedelta class values.
Example:

```
time_list
[datetime.timedelta(0, 23820), datetime.timedelta(0, 27480), datetime.timedelta(0, 28500), datetime.timedelta(0, 24180), datetime.timedelta(0, 27540), datetime.timedelta(0, 28920), datetime.timedelta(0, 28800), datetime.timedelta(0, 29100), datetime.timedelta(0, 29100), datetime.timedelta(0, 24480), datetime.timedelta(0, 27000)]
```

And these values meaning is as follow:

```
Total Time Spent on  2  is  6:37:00
Total Time Spent on  3  is  7:38:00
Total Time Spent on  4  is  7:55:00
Total Time Spent on  5  is  6:43:00
Total Time Spent on  8  is  7:39:00
Total Time Spent on  9  is  8:02:00
Total Time Spent on  10  is  8:00:00
Total Time Spent on  11  is  8:05:00
Total Time Spent on  12  is  8:05:00
Total Time Spent on  15  is  6:48:00
Total Time Spent on  16  is  7:30:00
```

Comment: It depends on what do you want to see on the ticks labels of the X axis on your bar plot. You already have the number of seconds spent on work ( e.g. 23820 = 60*60*6 + 60*37), so it's the matter of binning and labeling, according to your requirements.

Comment: @Maciek I want date on X-Axis and Time Spent on Y-Axis.
2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16 are dates and they should be on X-Axis
and the time, on Y-Axis.
So that I can plot graph, indicating that, on 2nd Jan -> 6:37 time spent
on 3rd Jan -> 7:38 time spend, and so on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While matplotlib can in principle handle datetime objects, the bar plot cannot interprete them directly. So one may add an arbitrary date to the timedeltas and convert to numbers using `matplotlib.dates.date2num()`. Then using a `DateFormatter` enables nice ticklabels.

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

days = [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16]

time_list = [datetime.timedelta(0, 23820), datetime.timedelta(0, 27480), 
             datetime.timedelta(0, 28500), datetime.timedelta(0, 24180), 
             datetime.timedelta(0, 27540), datetime.timedelta(0, 28920), 
             datetime.timedelta(0, 28800), datetime.timedelta(0, 29100), 
             datetime.timedelta(0, 29100), datetime.timedelta(0, 24480), 
             datetime.timedelta(0, 27000)]

# specify a date to use for the times
zero = datetime.datetime(2018,1,1)
time = [zero + t for t in time_list]
# convert datetimes to numbers
zero = mdates.date2num(zero)
time = [t-zero for t in mdates.date2num(time)]

f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(1,1,1)

ax.bar(days, time, bottom=zero)
ax.yaxis_date()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M"))

# add 10% margin on top (since ax.margins seems to not work here)
ylim = ax.get_ylim()
ax.set_ylim(None, ylim[1]+0.1*np.diff(ylim))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this solution.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I apologize for stepping out of line, but is it possible to do something similar using `plot` instead of `bar`? I tried to implement something similar but I end up getting a `ValueError: view limit minimum 0.01 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value`. I do apologize for hijacking your question, @xpress_embedo.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think you can directly plot `timedelta` in Matplotlib, but since you already have the number of seconds, you can define a custom tick format that converts seconds to hours and minutes.

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

def format_func(x, pos):
    hours = int(x//3600)
    minutes = int((x%3600)//60)
    seconds = int(x%60)

    return "{:d}:{:02d}".format(hours, minutes)
    # return "{:d}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(hours, minutes, seconds)

formatter = FuncFormatter(format_func)
```

Then, you can set the tick formatter for the y-axis.

Here's an example using a `bar`.

```
labels = [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16]
seconds = [i.seconds for i in time_list]
f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.bar(labels, seconds)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
# this locates y-ticks at the hours
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(base=3600))
# this ensures each bar has a 'date' label
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(base=1))
```

[image: Example Bar Graph]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately i am not much familiar with these functions, thanks for introducing this to me. I will read documentation and understand this more properly.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem when I wanted to plot the data with a `y axis` equal to `Timedelta64[ns]` type. I found the easiest solution to handle this issue from this blog : [solution](https://www.datasciencebytes.com/bytes/2015/05/16/pandas-timedelta-histograms-unit-conversion-and-overflow-danger/). For short, just change the `dtype` of your column to `.astype('timedelta64[m]')`. You can change to hour, minutes or seconds for your case just by changing the value in a square brackets. It changes the dtype of your `y` column to `float64` and then you can easily plot the bar graph or plot with normal units and not like nanoseconds