# how to make a bar plot in pandas v1.0

Tags: pandas, timedelta

I am trying to visualize the total number of calls made during the time interval, where `x` is a month and `y` is a sum of all calls made during that period.

I have a main DataFrame `df1` with various columns, where I take two columns with `'date'` and `'duration'` values and resample it to a monthly period:

`df2 = df1[['date', 'duration']]`

`monthly_df2 = df2.set_index('date').resample('M').sum()`

I can get a nice DataFrame with the data I want:

```
2018-10-31  03:03:34
2018-11-30  03:22:21
2018-12-31  04:31:56
2019-01-31  04:02:31
```

The problem starts when I  want to plot this data:

1. If I use plot() method directly to resampled DataFrame I can get a line graph, where y value is shown in nanoseconds, so value 03:03:34 transformed to 11014000000000 and so on.
2. When I use .plot.bar() method I have:

> TypeError: Passing integers to fillna for timedelta64[ns] dtype is no
>   longer supported.  To obtain the old behavior, pass
>   `pd.Timedelta(seconds=n)` instead.

I was looking through the stack overflow and other resources, but all the solutions for bar plots were posted before the pandas v1.0 was released and I also have same `TypeError` if I use those solutions.

They changed it to Timedelta concept, but I cannot understand how I can use it in my situation: 
[Timedelta](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/timedeltas.html)

Could anyone suggest me a good way to overcome this issue

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. The plotting works for me. I am on 1.0.3

Comment: I checked the ```monthly_df2.dtypes``` and get the following result:

```date          datetime64[ns]  ```

```duration    timedelta64[ns]  ```

```dtype: object```   

Can it be the reason?

Comment: I'm not sure why there's a `dtype: object` in there... that doesn't seem to lead to the error you're seeing, however.

Comment: @mechanical_meat so you mean I should have some ```datetime``` instead of ```object```?

Comment: Right, exactly.

Comment: I think my main problem comes from that the ```duration``` column is a ```timedelta64[ns]``` format. It works fine if I resample my ```date``` column into some period. But the problem comes when I want to plot the result by use ```.plot()``` method. The duration transforms into nanoseconds and my ```y``` axis becomes enormously huge numbers. And if I want to plot the bar graph, I have this ```TypeError``` which I mentioned before.

Comment: In case I make my ```duration``` column with ```pd.to_datetime(value, format="%H:%M:%S")``` in addition to my time in minutes and hours I got YEAR-MONTH-DAY like 1900-01-01. And then if I resample ```date``` and sum by ```duration``` I receive ```NaN```. So I am looking for the method to be able to solve this issue.

Comment: Actually it works fine if my ```y``` column is some integer value and then I resample and use ```.plot.bar()``` method. By my main idea is to show the duration in time

Comment: I'm glad you solved this!

Answer (score 2):

This is more correct name for my question [Plot datetime.timedelta using matplotlib and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48294332/plot-datetime-timedelta-using-matplotlib-and-python/61557664#61557664)
 and solution which could be also found in this blogpost: [solution](https://www.datasciencebytes.com/bytes/2015/05/16/pandas-timedelta-histograms-unit-conversion-and-overflow-danger/).

For short, just change the `dtype` of your column to `.astype('timedelta64[m]')`. You can change to hour, minutes or seconds for your case just by changing the value in a square brackets. It changes the dtype of your `y column` to `float64` and then you can easily plot the bar graph or plot with normal units and not like nanoseconds